# How to debug into iOS app XIB loading process?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I sometime accidentally delete a wire in XIB table which will cause my app crashed later, and i have to look into bunch of xib files to find the mistake. For a project with intricate XIBs, it might take time to figure out such the errors.

I wonder if there is a way to debug into XIBs loading process that could make it easier?

Thanks.
Lvr

Comment: You're not using svn or git with your project? It should be easy to track changes and undo them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Application Unit tests for verifying all your IBOutlets and objects, loaded from NIBs.